# License Maven Plugin changing the license name of a third party

Tags: java, maven, licensing

So I'm using License Maven Plugin to generate a report for our third party packages but I am facing a problem and don't know how to get around it. For some dependencies, the pom contains an invalid (incomplete) license. For example [this one](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final).

So what I have been trying to do is to change the license for those dependencies to the correct ones. I know about [this goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/examples/example-download-licenses.html) of License Maven Plugin but that's for downloading the licenses not generating the report (scroll to the end of that page).

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

License file for your example is inside jar file and also in comment of package pom file (http://mavensearch.io/pom/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final)

```
This program and the accompanying materials are made available under 
the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 and Eclipse Distribution         
License v. 1.0 which accompanies this distribution.
The Eclipse Public License is available at   
http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.htm
```

Comment: I'm aware of the license for that package, my question was how to use the license maven plugin to replace the wrong (incomplete) license information with the correct one.